# How to open an MP3 file from R without using a package

Tags: r, mp3

Can I open an MP3 file from the R console? I tried the `source` command but it's not working. My code is:

```
source(file=filedestination)
```

Below is the error:

> Error in source(file = "E:/Music_cx/EELS/Eels/Albums/1998 - Electro-Shock Blues/12 - Climbing to the Moon.mp3") :
> E:/Music_cx/EELS/Eels/Albums/1998 - Electro-Shock Blues/12 - Climbing to the Moon.mp3:1:4: unexpected input
> 1: ID3

I don't want to use a package for this. What can I try instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? You want to play it on your computer, or to access the binary data in R?

Comment: `source` is for reading R code from files. Read the help for a function before you try anything.

Comment: @KenBenoit: source access the input is what i understood. ya i want to play it from a windows media player or something. do i have to open that connection too. do you think there is any other command for the mentioned purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, `shell.exec("etcetc/foo.mp3")` should open the mp3 using the default program for that file, which is probably your mp3 player.

If you want a cross-platform solution that works on Windows, Mac and Linux, the best I can find is the `OpenFileInOS` function from the `pander` package. This uses R's `shell.exec` in Windows, and uses `system` to call `open` on Macs, and `xdg-open` in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

In mac:

You can use the system() function.

say you have an mp3 song named "05 - kite" in the "my music" directory:

```
system("cd \"my music\"; afplay \"05 - kite\".mp3")
```

Comment: i have a windows. system command should work for windows too right? i tried running but i am get a warning with no player opening.

Comment: afplay is for mac's terminal.

Comment: yeah i get that. but system command should work in windows setting too is what i was wondering.

Comment: Yes; system() works on windows too. so you just need to know the right command line code for playing mp3.

Comment: i think the syntax would be system("player.name song.location") but how do i identify name of the player which would be understood by the R.